# Some links in admin not working correctly

Tags: 7, users

I know this is a pretty "broad" issue, but I have several links in the admin interface that are not working correctly. One place in particular is in the Rules section of admin. When I edit a rule and add a new Condition, the "Data Selectors" fieldset text is not clickable (so I cannot expand it to see all of the available data selectors. Also, when I click in the "Data Selector" textbox field, the autocomplete is filled with "`<div></div>`" html wrappers around the data selectors. The attached screenshot shows both of these issues.

What would cause this? So far I have tried switching to Bartik theme (I use Seven as my default admin theme)... no change. I also updated all modules and updated Drupal core to the most recent version (7.27). My next step will be to disable modules, but I am quite hesitant to do so since I "need" all of the modules that are currently installed. I would appreciate any feedback and ideas on what might be causing this, and how it can be fixed.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally got an error message to work with (`TypeError: this.jqObject.data(...) is undefined`), which led me to this solution:  https://drupal.org/comment/8677587#comment-8677587:

> Hi guys, I am pretty new to Drupal and programming in general, so pleas bear with me... I got the data selector working by configuring the jQuery_update module:
>
> Default JQuery Version: 1.7
>
> Alternate JQuery Version: 1.7
>
> JQuery Compression Level: Development (I doubt this should make any differences)
>
> JQuery and JQuery UI CDN : JQuery